# Eror while working on Head First Ruby: undefined method `/' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

I have been working through *Head First Ruby* by Jay McGavren. I attempted to run a piece of code straight out of the book that should give this output:

```
Name: Jane Doe
Pay This Week: $1917.18
```

The code is:

```
class Employee
  attr_reader :name

  def name=(name)
    # Code to validate and set @name
  end
  def print_name
    puts "Name: #{name}"
  end
end

class SalariedEmployee < Employee
  attr_reader :salary

  def salary=(salary)
    # Code to validate and set @salary
  end
  def print_pay_stub
    print_name
    pay_for_period = (salary / 365.0) * 14
    formatted_pay = format("$%.2f", pay_for_period)
    puts "Pay This Period: #{formatted_pay}"
  end
end

salaried_employee = SalariedEmployee.new
salaried_employee.name = "Jane Doe"
salaried_employee.salary = 50000
salaried_employee.print_pay_stub
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I get this error:

```
in `print_pay_stub': undefined method `/' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: show the implementation of `#salary=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write logic to set @salary variable:

```
def salary=(salary)
  @salary = salary
end
```

Comment: Yes OP has the logic I believe. But OP has some more code there to validate, which we need to look. I asked for the same.

Comment: Yes this worked. Thank you very much. I'm very inexperienced in programming, not to mention in Ruby. I copied the code exactly like it was in the book and either it was wrong or the author assumed the reader would replace the comments with the appropriate code (although I'm not sure why he would assume this.)

Comment: @Daemon_X Oh I see. :) Good Luck! hehe

Comment: @Daemon_X please consider marking an answer as correct if it helped.